# Trying to understand recursion in objects and arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion, nested

I am trying to build a mysql query that adds items to a database.  The items are held inside an object that is formatted like:

```
object(PhealResult)#7 (5) {
  ["request_time"]=>
  string(19) "2011-08-04 14:14:37"
  ["request_time_unixtime"]=>
  int(1312467277)
  ["cached_until"]=>
  string(19) "2011-08-04 20:14:37"
  ["cached_until_unixtime"]=>
  int(1312488877)
  ["_element:private"]=>
  object(PhealElement)#12 (3) {
    ["_name"]=>
    string(6) "result"
    ["_value"]=>
    object(PhealContainer)#11 (1) {
      ["_container:private"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["assets"]=>
        object(PhealRowSet)#14 (3) {
          [0]=>
          object(PhealRowSetRow)#19 (6) {
            ["itemID"]=>
            string(13) "1003152969505"
            ["locationID"]=>
            string(8) "30000157"
            ["typeID"]=>
            string(5) "11489"
            ["quantity"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["flag"]=>
            string(1) "0"
            ["singleton"]=>
            string(1) "1"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(PhealRowSetRow)#18 (7) {
            ["itemID"]=>
            string(9) "290900396"
            ["locationID"]=>
            string(8) "66002198"
            ["typeID"]=>
            string(2) "27"
            ["quantity"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["flag"]=>
            string(2) "71"
            ["singleton"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["contents"]=>
            object(PhealRowSet)#24 (15) {
              [0]=>
              object(PhealRowSetRow)#29 (5) {
                ["itemID"]=>
                string(13) "1003305129036"
                ["typeID"]=>
                string(4) "2183"
                ["quantity"]=>
                string(1) "4"
                ["flag"]=>
                string(3) "117"
                ["singleton"]=>
                string(1) "0"
              }
              **cropped**
            }
          }
          **cropped**
         }
        }
       }
      }
```

Pay particular attention to how the nesting works. The top level rowset is named "assets", but then each item in there can have "contents." Each item in that can also have a "contents" list. There's a limit to how far it can go in terms of EVE but the limit is unknown and the code should assume there's no real limit.

I have played around a little with the one of the code snippets located on the http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php which appears to be down as of now.

```
    function array_value_recursive($key, array $arr){
        $val = null;
        array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use($key, &$val){
            $val = $k == $key ? $v : (!is_null($val) ? $val : false);
        });
        return $val;
    }
```

I cannot seem to wrap my head around how to work with the object / array given that I do not know how deep it goes.  How do I know how far in I am and how do I access the data contained when i am x deep in the object/ array.  I thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

The code below is the code I was using before I knew that there can be a somewhat endless nested "contents".  I have included this code so you can see what it is that I am trying to accomplish.

```
try { 
            $corpPheal = new Pheal($fullUserID, $fullAPIKey, "corp");

                $corpAssetList = $corpPheal->AssetList(array('characterID'=>$fullCharID));

                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($corpAssetList);
                echo "</pre>";


        }
        catch (PhealException $e) {
            echo 'error: ' . $e->code . ' meesage: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $numOfAssetList = count($corpAssetList->assets);


        for ($i =0; $i <= ($numOfAssetList -1); $i++){

            $numOfAssetContents = count($corpAssetList->assets[$i]->contents);
            echo $numOfAssetContents . "<br>\n";

            if ($numOfAssetContents > 0){
                $count = 0;
                for ($j=0; $j <= ($numOfAssetContents - 1); $j++){
                    echo "i = $i, j = $j <br>\n";
                    $count++;
                    foreach ($corpAssetList->assets[$i]->contents[$j] as $key => $value){

                        switch ($key) {
                            case "itemID":
                                $qry = "INSERT INTO eve_asset_list(`itemID`, `typeID`, `quantity`, `flag`, `singleton`) VALUES('$value','";
                                break;

                            case "typeID":
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "','";
                                break;
                            case "quantity":
                                $quantity = $value;
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "','";
                                break;
                            case "flag":
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "','";
                                break;
                            case "singleton":
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = $quantity";
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    $result = mysql_query($qry);
                    include "./includes/mysqlError.inc.php";
                }
            }else {

                foreach ($corpAssetList->assets[$i] as $key => $value){

                        switch ($key) {
                            case "itemID":
                                $qry = "INSERT INTO eve_asset_list(`itemID`, `typeID`, `quantity`, `flag`, `singleton`) VALUES('$value','";
                                break;

                            case "typeID":
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "','";
                                break;
                            case "quantity":
                                $quantity = $value;
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "','";
                                break;
                            case "flag":
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "','";
                                break;
                            case "singleton":
                                $qry = $qry . $value . "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = $quantity";
                                break;
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is it the concept of recursion that's bugging you or how to do it with php?

Comment: I do not understand how to make the recursion happen so that when i write my mysql statement I will be working with the data at x location with in the array/object.  Initially i did not know that the object / array could continue to grow in depth and was using multiple nested for statements but this method will be very bloated.  I know the answer is using recursion to get the result I am looking for but i dont quite understand how I know where i am and how to get the data that is at the location that I am at. I do understand the concept of recursion as in a function that calls its self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code snippet now does is apply a function to every element [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php). This is a predefined function in PHP.

The function that is applied right now looks whether the current key equals the one that's given as a parameter. If they're equal it stores the value and otherwise not.

Eventually the first found value is returned. This return value can be an array itself and you could use it to access internal data.

At the moment it doesn't do anything with the deepness of the data. Is this something that you want to change? If yes, What would you like the function to do?

**Edit:**

You'd probably need something like

```
function insert_all($pheal_row_set)
{
    foreach($pheal_row_set as $pheal_row_set_row)
    {
        foreach($pheal_row_set_row as $key => $value)
        {
            //switch statment
        }
        //insert
        if(!is_null($pheal_row_set_row['contents']) &&
            is_array($pheal_row_set_row['contents']))
        {
            insert_all($pheal_row_set_row['contents']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my OP so that I can show you what it is that I am trying to accomplish in the context that I am working.  Now given that I do not understand this level of coding that well my next statement may be incorrect.  I do not think I need to be concerned with how deep I am so long as I can get the data that is located at that depth.

Comment: I made an edit. If you need more explanation, just ask. I kept the names from the objects you gave, so note the difference between `$pheal_row_set` and `$pheal_row_set_row`

Comment: I am not sure if this function takes into account that a "contents" may contain items and "contents".  All items must be added.  if a "contents" is encountered then its items must be added and if it has "contents" they must be evaluated in the same way.  Your solution is very close and I am trying to fully understand it and modify it to produce the correct results.  I am plussing your answer because you technically answer the title question.

Comment: If you can put code similar to `if (is_array($pheal_row_set_row) || is_object($pheal_row_set_row)){ //Switch }else{ foreach($pheal_row_set_row as $key => $value)
        {
            //switch statment
        }}`  I will mark it correct.  I hope that this edit makes sense.  If it does not let me know and i will edit your post to reflect the necessary changes

Comment: I put the `is_array` in the guard of the recursive call. I don't think much more is needed to the structure. `PhealRowSet` is an array of `PhealRowSetRow`s. So all these are traversed. With such a row an insert query is build and if this row contains a `PhealRowSet` in its contents the same thing is done to it. Maybe it's neater to use [`instance of`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) in this situation.

Comment: i think the issue with what you have up there is that it does not look if a container has items and arrays only if it has arrays.  Please correct me if I am wrong.  I know that of the 700 items in question when i run it the way you have it above it returns 500, when you make the changes i suggested it returns the full set.  I am going to edit your answer and you let me know if it makes sense

Comment: I'm not fully aware of the structure of your data (since it's cropped here). So go ahead and try some changes. Maybe it'll improve my understanding of the question/problem.

Comment: Yes, by no means was i knocking what you did because you answered the title question perfectly and wrote code that is very reusable and will be useful to others.  The part of the OP beneath the Object example was my attempt to describe how the data will be but I think I left out the part that an object can have objects and items in which the objects have more objects and items.